# css html simple logic problem

Tags: html, css

How do I get the p-tag with text "jon harris" beside the p-tag with text "Room 2"
I have tried float-combinations.. but there is something missing..i guess.

here the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html lang="en">  
    <head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <title>Twitter Avatar Scrolling</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/events.css" />  
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="event">
            <img src="images/red.jpg" alt="picture" />  
            <p>Room 2</p>
            <p class="patient-name">Jon Harris</p>
            <p class="event-text">This is a pixel. A flying pixel!</p>
            <p class="event-timestamp">feb 2 2011 - 23:01</p>
        </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

here is the css:

```
body {  
    font:13px/1.5 "helvetica neue", helvetica, arial, san-serif;  
}  
.event {  
    display:block;  
    background: #ececec;  
    width:380px;  
    padding:10px;  
    margin:10px;  
    overflow:hidden;  
    text-align: left;
}  
.event img {  
    float:left;  
}  
.event p {  
    margin:0;  
    padding-left:60px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.patient-name {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.event-text{
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.event-timestamp{
    color: #000;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the <p> 'paragraph' tag. - might as well use <span class='CSS_class'> Text </span>

Comment: What's the desired look? Kind of like they were in table cells next to each other with spacing between or simply different looking text in a string? If it's the latter then what @Rob said would be fine. Otherwise we can do some code examples.

Comment: I want it to look like this: http://imm.io/5tzg - I have to have diffrent tags becuse, i am fetching data from at database and implementing i those events..so every div is going to have diffrent values with the same p-tag, spang-tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go ... http://jsfiddle.net/2N6tu/

You just need to turn the first two `<p>` elements to inline elements.

Comment: Which version of safari and firefox? It looks like http://imm.io/5u2v in FF 3.5 and 4, Chrome 11, IE8 and 9, and Opera 11

Comment: Try playing with the `padding` for the `.event p` selector. If that doesn't work, try the margin.

Comment: .event p {  
 margin: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: I need to change the margin, thanks alot guys! this place rocks! =)

Comment: did that fix it for safari? Which version was it, just out of interest?

Comment: ooh, and best way to say *thanks* is to click the tick in this block. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper around those two P tags, set the width of those two P tags and add float: left to both e.g:

```
    <div class="event">
        <img src="images/red.jpg" alt="picture" />
        <div class="event-wrapper">
            <div class="event-inner-wrap">
                 <p class="room-number">Room 2</p>
                 <p class="patient-name">Jon Harris</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p class="event-text">This is a pixel. A flying pixel!</p>
            <p class="event-timestamp">feb 2 2011 - 23:01</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.event-wrapper {
    width: 300px; /*** assuming that image is 80px, i didn't measure ***/
    float: left;
}

.event-inner-wrap {
    width: 300px; /*** assuming that image is 80px, i didn't measure ***/
}

p.room-number {
    width: 150px; /** set as whatever you like, just make sure this width plus the width of the patient name is no bigger than the wrapper width **/
    float: left;
}


p.patient-name {
    width: 150px; /** set as whatever you like, just make sure this width plus the width of the room number is no bigger than the wrapper width **/
    float: left;
}
```

Good luck.

**Edit**, because I saw that image you posted after I added this.
**Edit again**, because you don't need the extra `clear: both;` and I missed off 2 semi's.

**Note**, if you end up using Span tags instead of P the same above principle applies, however, the Span will require a `display: block;` on them if setting widths etc.

Comment: Accidentally left off two semi's after the two "width: 150px;". Also remove the "clear: both;" as I added that before I saw the image of what you were trying to do. If you make these ammends it should work, it works fine for me, I just tested. Best of luck.  (I just edited the above code (also, if you do change to Span's take in to consideration what I said above, plus change that CSS to span.class instead of p.class).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```css
.event p{display:inline;}
```